# Azure AD: Property 'mail' is read-only and cannot be set

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I was trying to create a user in Azure AD without `mail` filed is user created successfully. I need to add the email id in Azure AD at the time of user created.

I added the `mail` property in json and it says

> Property 'mail' is read-only and cannot be set.

My C# code is:

```cs
var url = string.Format("https://graph.windows.net/{0}/users?api-version=1.6",oauthsettings.TenantId);
var authDetails = _orchardServices.WorkContext.CurrentSite.As<AzureAuthenticationPart>();

var alogin = new AzureLogin();
var jwttoken = alogin.ServiceAuth(authDetails.ClientId, authDetails.ClientSecret);
var aadUser =new {
  mail=email,
  accountEnabled = true,
  displayName = userName,
  mailNickname = userName,
  passwordProfile = new passwordProfile()
  {
    password = password,
    forceChangePasswordNextLogin = authDetails.IsUpdatePwdNextLogin
  },
  userPrincipalName = userName + oauthsettings.DirectoryName,
};
var client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + jwttoken);
var modelval = Convert.ToString(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(aadUser));
var content = new StringContent(modelval, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var result = client.PostAsync(url, content).Result;
```

Get Access Token from Azure AD After Login

```cs
JwtSecurityToken token = GetAccessToken(authDetails, code, returnUrl);
var claims = token.Claims;
return LogOn(claims, returnUrl);
```

Getting Email from JWT

```cs
public LogOnResponse LogOn(IEnumerable<System.Security.Claims.Claim> claims, string returnUrl)
{
  var email = claims.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Type == "email").Value;
```

In this place I can't get the access token, because the user created time is not set the email in Graph API Request. I have another problem is this email id based only I was validate another site also, so I was required set the email in user created time.

I required email id for login in my application. i was integrate the Azure AD in existing application it's required for email.

Does anyone know how to set the email id in Azure AD for a user.

My Request in Postman. Response for Email Added in Request

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you looked at [Azure AD B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-overview)? Seems like you are managing external users with all sorts of different emails in your application which is better suited for Azure AD B2C.

Answer (score 3):

Because the mail attribute is tied to Exchange Online, we don't permit you to write to that attribute unless you have an Exchange Online license.  When you activate a license for the user, Exchange Online will update the field with the correct mailbox mail address during the creation of the user's mailbox.  You can utilize "MailNickName" and " other emails" during the creation of a user.  This field will also depend upon if it is a "local account (B2C)" or "work or school account".

I hope this answers your question concerning the "mail" attribute being "read-only"

Comment: thanks, any link to official MS documentation about that?

Answer (score 2):

There are two different fields for Email Addresses on an AAD User.

From the [Graph API Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#user-entity):

> **mail**
>
> ```
> POST, GET ($filter)
> ```
>
> The SMTP address for the user, for example, "jeff@contoso.onmicrosoft.com".

> **otherMails**
>
> ```
> POST, GET ($filter), PATCH
> ```
>
> A list of additional email addresses for the user; for example: ["bob@contoso.com", "Robert@fabrikam.com"].

Note that you can only set the `mail` property when you initially create the user (POST), but you can update the `otherMails` property whenever you want (PATCH).

It seems like you should be using the `otherMails` property for your needs.